# Apollo RESTDataSource calling other RESTDataSource?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, restdatasource

Say I have an 2 API classes that extend RESTDataSource:

```
class MoviesAPI extends RESTDataSource {
async getMovies() {}
}

class SongsAPI extends RESTDataSource {
async getSongs() {}
}
```

How can I call `getSongs` from `getMovies` within the existing Apollo server context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the apollo server context via `this.context` in the datasource class and get `dataSources` via `this.context.dataSources`.

E.g.

`server.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';
import { MoviesAPI } from './MoviesAPI';
import { SongsAPI } from './SongsAPI';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    movies: String
  }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    movies: (_, __, { dataSources }) => {
      return dataSources.moviesAPI.getMovies();
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => {
    return {
      moviesAPI: new MoviesAPI(),
      songsAPI: new SongsAPI(),
    };
  },
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Apollo server is listening on ${url}`);
});
```

`MoviesAPI.ts`:

```js
import { RESTDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-rest';

export class MoviesAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  async getMovies() {
    const songs = await this.context.dataSources.songsAPI.getSongs();
    const movies = ['a', 'b'];
    return JSON.stringify({ movies, songs });
  }
}
```

`SongsAPI.ts`:

```js
import { RESTDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-rest';

export class SongsAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  async getSongs() {
    return ['x', 'y'];
  }
}
```

Send a GraphQL query from the client-side:

```js
query{
  movies
}
```

Response payload:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "movies": "{\"movies\":[\"a\",\"b\"],\"songs\":[\"x\",\"y\"]}"
  }
}
```

Package versions: `"apollo-datasource-rest": "^0.8.1"`, `"apollo-server": "^2.12.0"`

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/61425326

Comment: I think this solution doesn't work anymore, `this.context.dataSources` is empty in my case :/

Comment: Ah sorry, i was just checking `this.context.dataSources` in the initialize function of the `RESTDataSource` class where it was undefined. When using `this.context.dataSources` from inside the class's functions, it works :)